# TaxonomyService - Processing found keywords (0)

Tags: 2011-sp1, taxonomy

My problem is that I'm not retrieving taxonomies from the Broker DB in **one particular environment**.

We have four environments, dev, test, staging, production. Taxonomies are returning OK from dev, test, staging. Not on live. The records **do exist** in the Keywords table in the live Broker database.

In the core log on staging for example, I see the following when we do a fresh request to a page:

> CollectionLoadContext - 69 collections were found in result set for
>   role: com.tridion.storage.TaxonomyItem.keywordRelations
>   TaxonomyService - Processing found keywords (69)

In the core log on live, I see the following when we do a fresh request to a page:

> TaxonomyService - Processing found keywords (0)

(the 'CollectionLoadContext' debug lines are missing completely from live)

All jar files in the **website's*** lib folder are identical on both servers.
All configs files in the **website's*** config folder are almost identical (except for the actual datasource details) on both servers.

- by website I mean `E:\inetpub\allwebsites\website1\bin\lib` | `E:\inetpub\allwebsites\website1\bin\config`

The files & configs in the 'main'* Tridion directory (ie NOT the website specific `bin\lib` or `bin\config` folders) do differ from the website specific ones (for example, they have si4t configs in & other stuff - but, as I understand it, these shouldn't be interfering if the website has it's own configs/libs)

- by main I mean `E:\Tridion\lib` | `E:\Tridion\config`

**In response to Bart's comment:**

```
using Tridion.ContentDelivery.Taxonomies;
...
TaxonomyFactory _taxonomyFactory = new TaxonomyFactory(); 
_category = _taxonomyFactory.GetTaxonomyKeywords(categoryUriToLookIn, compFilter,new TaxonomyHierarchyFormatter());
```

The staging/live both use the same CM instance/database, so I don't think it's a difference in publication URIs

Comment: What is the code/query that you use on this page, and could there be a difference in (Publication) URIs between the different environments, or are all basically a copy of the CM Database?

Comment: Better edit your question and add the info in there, so you can delete the comment

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, you haven't published category to LIVE.

Hence you are getting message as

> TaxonomyService - Processing found keywords (0)

Otherwise message shows as

> TaxonomyService - Processing found keywords (69)

Comment: Hi Siva - as I said in my question, "The records do exist in the Keywords table in the live Broker database." - I have verified the category & keywords are in the database.

Comment: In the TAXFACETS table? This is the table used for Taxonomies

Comment: This appears to be the problem. Thanks Nuno!